# Failed to initialize node <>: Failed to create event log dir with 404 HTTP response code and 22 exit code See output in

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

Getting the following error:

```
Failed to initialize node b9999v0-periodic-publisher-dataproc-cluster-m: Failed to create event log dir with 404 HTTP response code and 22 exit code See output in: gs://bcdc-b9999v0-dataproc-staging-bucket/google-cloud-dataproc-metainfo/27b950f4-e60d-4952-8450-67129ab8f70e/b9999v0-periodic-publisher-dataproc-cluster-m/dataproc-startup-script_output
```

After examining the script_output it says -

```
activate-component-hive-metastore[3782]: nc: connect to b9999v0-periodic-publisher-dataproc-cluster-m port 9083 (tcp) failed: Connection refused.
```

I am not sure how to continue with this error, and what is wrong.

I am using terraform to create the cluster on GCP,

any help is appreciated!

Terraform code -

```
resource "google_dataproc_cluster" "pp_dataproc_cluster" {
  name    = local.periodic_publisher_dataproc_cluster_name
  region  = local.gcp_region
  project = local.gcp_project

  cluster_config {
    staging_bucket = local.dataproc_staging_bucket_name
    gce_cluster_config {
      internal_ip_only = true
      subnetwork       = data.terraform_remote_state.pt_infra.outputs.subnetwork_self_link
      service_account  = local.dataproc_worker_service_account_email
    }
    encryption_config {
      kms_key_name = module.cmek_for_regional_managed_resources.key_path
    }
    master_config {
      num_instances = 1
      machine_type  = local.double_cpu_machine_type
    }
    worker_config {
      num_instances = 2
      machine_type  = local.double_cpu_machine_type
    }
    software_config {
      override_properties = {
        "dataproc:dataproc.allow.zero.workers"     = "true"
        "hive:hive.metastore.schema.verification"  = "false"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your issue by providing more information about the step at which you are encountering the error message and how you are creating the cluster?

Comment: I am creating the cluster resource with Terraform, it looks like it fails when initiating the cluster. The error itself is printed on the GCP console log explorer, and I have no idea how can I get more information regarding it.

Comment: @kiranmathew added the terraform code

Comment: Is it possible from your side to [create](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/guides/create-cluster) a cluster without using terraform?